# value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I get this error:

```
value join is not a member of 
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (Int, (Long, String, Array[_0])))
        forSome { type _0 <: (String, Double) }]
```

The only suggestion I found is `import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._` I am already doing that.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: changing the code to eliminate `forSome` (i.e., when the object has type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (Int, (Long, String, Array[(String, Double)])))`) solved the problem.
Is this a bug in Spark?

Comment: `join` is a member of `org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions`. You forgot to include the line of code that gives you the error.

Comment: @DanielDarabos: the code is `foo.join(bar)`; the type of `foo` is in the error message - and it is clearly a subtype of a `Pair`.

Comment: wdym? you have a `forSome` type and `join` works?

Comment: Sorry, I had ignored the second half of the type in the error message. It's a good question.

Comment: You mean the upvoter? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`join` is a member of `org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions`. So why does the implicit class not trigger?

```
scala> val s = Seq[(Long, (Int, (Long, String, Array[_0]))) forSome { type _0 <: (String, Double) }]()
scala> val r = sc.parallelize(s)
scala> r.join(r) // Gives your error message.
scala> val p = new org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions(r)
<console>:25: error: no type parameters for constructor PairRDDFunctions: (self: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)])(implicit kt: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K], implicit vt: scala.reflect.ClassTag[V], implicit ord: Ordering[K])org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions[K,V] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (Int, (Long, String, Array[_0]))) forSome { type _0 <: (String, Double) }])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (Int, (Long, String, Array[_0]))) forSome { type _0 <: (String, Double) }]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(?K, ?V)]
Note: (Long, (Int, (Long, String, Array[_0]))) forSome { type _0 <: (String, Double) } >: (?K, ?V), but class RDD is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as -T instead. (SLS 4.5)
       val p = new org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions(r)
               ^
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (Int, (Long, String, Array[_0]))) forSome { type _0 <: (String, Double) }]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, V)]
       val p = new org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions(r)
```

I'm sure that error message is clear to everyone else, but just for my own slow self let's try to make sense of it. `PairRDDFunctions` has two type parameters, `K` and `V`. Your `forSome` is for the whole pair, so it cannot be split into separate `K` and `V` types. There are no `K` and `V` that `RDD[(K, V)]` would equal your RDD type.

However, you could have the `forSome` only apply to the key, instead of the whole pair. Join works now, because this type can be separated into `K` and `V`.

```
scala> val s2 = Seq[(Long, (Int, (Long, String, Array[_0])) forSome { type _0 <: (String, Double) })]()
scala> val r2 = sc.parallelize(2s)
scala> r2.join(r2)
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, ((Int, (Long, String, Array[_0])) forSome { type _0 <: (String, Double) }, (Int, (Long, String, Array[_0])) forSome { type _0 <: (String, Double) }))] = MapPartitionsRDD[5] at join at <console>:26
```

Comment: thanks! I wonder if it is possible to mode `forSome` inside for an _existing_ sequence.

Comment: I've managed to do the opposite with `s2.map { case (k, v) => k -> v }`. _(No idea what I'm doing...)_

Comment: Ah, I think this works: `s.map(_._1).zip(s.map(_._2))` (Zipping RDDs has the same effect!)

Comment: On second thought, it would be horrible to spend CPU cycles on this at run time. Could you just use a cast?

Comment: I solved the problem but not creating the implicit class in the first place.

Comment: Does your [`zip`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29268210/850781) solution scan the RDD twice?

Comment: Yes, it goes through the RDD twice. It's a really bad idea for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 2 Spark RDDs to be joined together..

Say, `rdd1.first` is in the form of `(Int, Int, Float) = (1,957,299.98)`
while `rdd2.first` is something like `(Int, Int) = (25876,1)` where the join is supposed to take place on the 1st field from both the RDDs.

> scala> rdd1.join(rdd2)  --- results in an error :**: error:
>   value join is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int,
>   Float)]

REASON

---

Both the RDDs should be in the form of a Key-Value pair.

Here, rdd2 -- being in the form of (1,957,299.98) -- does not obey this rule.. While rdd1 -- which is in the form of (25876,1) -- does.

RESOLUTION

---

Convert the output of the 1st RDD from `(1,957,299.98)` to a Key-Value pair in the form of `(1,(957,299.98))` before joining it with rdd2, as shown below:

```
scala> val rdd1KV = rdd1.map(x=>(x.split(",")(1).toInt,(x.split(",")(2).toInt,x.split(",")(4).toFloat))) -- modified RDD

scala> rdd1KV.join(rdd2) -- join successful :)
res**: (Int, (Int, Float)) = (1,(957,299.98))
```

By the way, join is the member of org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions. So make sure you import this on your Eclipse or IDE, wherever you want to run your code.

Article also on my blog:

https://tips-to-code.blogspot.com/2018/08/apache-spark-error-resolution-value.html