# Which operations preserve RDD order?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

RDD has a *meaningful* (as opposed to some random order imposed by the storage model) order if it was processed by [`sortBy()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#sortBy%28scala.Function1,%20boolean,%20int,%20scala.math.Ordering,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag%29), as explained in this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29281548/850781).

Now, which operations **preserve** that order?

E.g., is it ***guaranteed*** that (after `a.sortBy()`)

```
a.map(f).zip(a) === 
a.map(x => (f(x),x))
```

How about

```
a.filter(f).map(g) === 
a.map(x => (x,g(x))).filter(f(_._1)).map(_._2)
```

what about

```
a.filter(f).flatMap(g) === 
a.flatMap(x => g(x).map((x,_))).filter(f(_._1)).map(_._2)
```

Here "equality" `===` is understood as "functional equivalence", i.e., there is no way to distinguish the outcome using user-level operations (i.e., without reading logs &c).

Comment: I guess that any operation that changes the elements in an RDD cannot be expected to preserve order. eg. `intRdd.map(x=>x*-1)`. On rdds with a key, there're dedicated operations that preserve the order `pairRDD.mapValues` and pairRDD.flatMapValues` - not sure if there's a generalization that could satisfy this question- hence the comment.

Comment: RDDs are immutable; all operation create new RDDs.

Comment: look at the last line of the question, I am talking about functional equivalence rather than physical identity

Comment: @maasg: That's different from how I think this works. I've added an answer, but please let me know if you disagree. Especially if you can provide a counter-example in `spark-shell`. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielDarabos I misinterpreted the question and my comment was me thinking in terms of "collection being sorted" rather than preservation of the element ordering.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

All operations preserve the order, except those that explicitly do not. Ordering is always "meaningful", not just after a `sortBy`. For example, if you read a file (`sc.textFile`) the lines of the RDD will be in the order that they were in the file.

Without trying to give a complete list, `map`, `filter` and `flatMap` do preserve the order. `sortBy`, `partitionBy`, `join` do not preserve the order.

The reason is that most RDD operations work on `Iterator`s inside the partitions. So `map` or `filter` just has no way to mess up the order. You can take a look at the [**code**](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v1.3.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd) to see for yourself.

You may now ask: What if I have an RDD with a `HashPartitioner`. What happens when I use `map` to change the keys? Well, they will stay in place, and now the RDD is not partitioned by the key. You can use `partitionBy` to restore the partitioning with a shuffle.

Comment: Daniel, I was expecting something like that as well, where only a shuffle step would break the ordering,  but it seems that RDD ordering is coincidental and not contractual. This was a good thread: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3098  What I don't understand is this question after getting that info on a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268210/mind-blown-rdd-zip-method/29281548#29268210

Comment: I haven't read SPARK-3098 fully, but it uses `distinct`. `distinct` has to build a hashmap of the lines, so it loses the ordering. In the other question I think Sean is saying the same thing, that RDDs have an ordering. They are not multisets.

Comment: I can confirm that repartition does *not* preserve order, as far as I can tell. If I run `x = sc.textFile('somefile'); y = x.repartition(100); a = x.collect(); b = y.collect()`, then `a==b` is returns `False`.

Comment: @moustachio: Oops, thanks! You're right. `repartition` calls `coalesce` with `shuffle=true`, so it's obvious it will _shuffle_ the RDD. I've fixed the list.

Comment: The question has a lot more votes than my answer. I wonder if I am missing something that people are looking for. Let me know if my answer did not satisfy you! Thanks.

Comment: I think creating a dataframe from an RDD using `toDF` does not preserve order, just my 2 cents

Comment: @architectonic: What makes you think that? [The code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/ExistingRDD.scala#L31) just does a `map` on an iterator, so it does not change the order. Also a simple `sc.parallelize(1 to 100, 10).toDF.show(100)` test shows the RDD in the original order.

Comment: i am not quite sure if it 'preserves' the order with coalesce when you merge multiple partitions, which partitions goes into the final partition first? that would matter for the final order.

Comment: @MinnieShi: If partitions 2 and 3 get coalesced into one partition then it will just chain the iterators from partitions 2 and 3, so the new partition will contain the elements of partition 2 in order followed by the elements of partition 3 in order. Is this unclear in the answer? Or do you know it to be wrong?

Comment: @DanielDarabos I'm missing a general comment avoid the side effects of the transformations in the RDD. I mean, what is the amortized complexity in a particular executor? Is it more like a hash-table, or a tree? It's not a pure sequence/vector as that would need another data structure and time to keep the order. After many transformations, I'm confused about how you can keep both the order and have a feasible implementation that allows the fast operations required in the executors.

Comment: @hectorpal: No idea what you are speaking about. Take `map` for example. Items come in order, and get transformed one by one. It is very easy to keep the order, no data structure is needed. We would need a data structure to _change_ the order: we would need to put some input items in the data structure and output them later. (This is what `distinct` does, for example.) But if you need more details you can take a look at the source code (this part is very readable) or ask a separate question.

Comment: Ok, let's focus on map and add a filter step. If items are partitioned, they will be processed in order inside each node Mi. Suppose the results, mapped plus filtered, are to be moved to one single node C for a final processing. Nodes Mi have different speeds so the result of map won't arrive in order to C. What data structure would be used in C for preserving the order? Let's assume the items have some sort of index. C is receiving items with an index, but C doesn't know how many will arrive. It could be more efficient to store without ordering. How is the order preserved? yes, source code...

Comment: There is no push in Spark, it's all pull. Machine C will fetch (pull) the blocks in order.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you. It's interesting this could affect memory use in Mi nodes. A faster node could have memory problems if it's producing results too fast.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how it works out (or even how the code we are talking about looks), but almost certainly it has no memory impact. Either the results are only generated as they are requested, or they are written to disk as they are produced and then served from disk when the fetch comes.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Darabos, in response to your comment (Sep 13 at 8:59). Thank you for the clarification. I did not know that partition 1 will go in before partition 2 etc. And I've tested since, correct, the final order is still correct after using the coalesce. Thank you.

Comment: Does `select` preserve the order of rows?

Answer (score 5):

In Spark 2.0.0+ `coalesce` doesn't guarantee partitions order during merge. [DefaultPartitionCoalescer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/CoalescedRDD.scala) has optimization algorithm which is based on partition locality. When a partition contains information about its locality `DefaultPartitionCoalescer` tries to merge partitions on the same host. And only when there is no locality information it simply splits partition based on their index and preserves partitions order.

**UPDATE:**

If you load DataFrame from files, like parquet, Spark breaks order when it plans file splits. You can see it in [DataSourceScanExec.scala#L629](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/43b23fd1329f541ab98e27ea728bfcca9404c672/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/DataSourceScanExec.scala#L629) or in new Spark 3.x [FileScan#L152](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/43b23fd1329f541ab98e27ea728bfcca9404c672/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/FileScan.scala#L152) if you use it. It just sorts partitions by size and the splits which are less than `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` gets to last partitions.

So, if you need to load sorted dataset from files you need to implement your own reader.

Comment: Anecdotally I can confirm this is correct.  When I switched from Spark 2 to Spark 3 I started noticing that some of my data was occasionally losing its sortedness.  The job building that data was doing `df.sort(...).coalesce(...)`, and switching that job to use `df.coalesce(...).sort(...)` seems to have fixed the problem.  (Though TBF I could never seem to reproduce the issue in my testing - I just haven't found any unsorted data after making this change.)