# Can Dataframe joins in Spark preserve order?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently trying to join two DataFrames together but retain the same order in one of the Dataframes.

From [Which operations preserve RDD order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284095/which-operations-preserve-rdd-order), it seems that (correct me if this is inaccurate because I'm new to Spark) joins do not preserve order because rows are joined / "arrive" at the final dataframe not in a specified order due to the data being in different partitions.

How could one perform a join of two DataFrames while preserving the order of one table?

E.g.,

`+------------+---------+
 |    col1    |  col2   |
 +------------+---------+
 | 0          | a       |
 | 1          | b       |
 +------------+---------+`

joined with

`+------------+---------+
 |    col2    |  col3   |
 +------------+---------+
 | b          | x       |
 | a          | y       |
 +------------+---------+`

on **col2** should give

`+------------+--------------------+
 |    col1    |  col2   |    col 3 |
 +------------+---------+----------+
 | 0          | a       |     y    |
 | 1          | b       |     x    |
 +------------+---------+----------+`

I've heard some things about using `coalesce` or `repartition`, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions/methods/insights are appreciated.

**Edit**: would this be analogous to having one reducer in MapReduce? If so, how would that look like in Spark?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882529/how-to-zip-twoor-more-dataframe-in-spark

Comment: I don't think zip would work because the rows from table 2 should be joined to rows from table 1 while preserving order, not that row 1 goes with row 1', etc, and similarly for the method of indexing and joining.

Comment: I just noticed from your example above that col2 is being used for the join condition.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, col2 should be the join condition. I'm sorry if that was not clear, will edit the question.

Comment: In that case, I expect Spark will maintain the order in the resulting dataframe.  So if you perform `a.join(b, a.col2=b.col2)` then the resulting dataframe should be ordered by a. The order of the dataframe should only really matter to if you perform a take or collect in spark.  If there's a natural order you want, then you could always just sort the dataframe.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, and it seems like you should be able to save a shuffle operation if this were implemented as an argument for `join`

Comment: I tried joining, and it looks like it might be just ordering by the key of `a`, but not ordering by `col1`. If this is true, then it makes sense, but I'm looking for an ordering based on something other than the key.

Answer (score 6):

It can't. You can add `monotonically_increasing_id` and reorder data after join.