# Pyspark: Add new column from another pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes as follows.
I want to add a new column to dataframe `df_a` from dataframe `df_b` column `val_1` based on the condition `df_a.col_p == df_b.id`

```
df_a = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1412, 31, 1), (2422, 21, 1), (4223, 22, 2), (
    2244, 43, 1), (1235, 54, 1), (4126, 12, 5), (2342, 44, 1 )], ["idx", "col_n", "col_p"])
df_a.show()

+----+-----+-----+
| idx|col_n|col_p|
+----+-----+-----+
|1412|   31|    1|
|2422|   21|    1|
|4223|   22|    2|
|2244|   43|    1|
|1235|   54|    1|
|4126|   12|    5|
|2342|   44|    1|
+----+-----+-----+
```

```
df_b = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (
    4, 1, 1), (5, 2, 1), (6, 2, 2)], ["id", "val_1", "val_2"])
df_b.show()

+---+-----+-----+
| id|val_1|val_2|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|    1|    1|
|  2|    1|    1|
|  3|    1|    2|
|  4|    1|    1|
|  5|    2|    1|
|  6|    2|    2|
+---+-----+-----+
```

**Expected output**

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+
| idx|col_n|col_p|val_1|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|1412|   31|    1|    1|
|2422|   21|    1|    1|
|4223|   22|    2|    1|
|2244|   43|    1|    1|
|1235|   54|    1|    1|
|4126|   12|    5|    2|
|2342|   44|    1|    1|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

**My code**

```
cond = (df_a.col_p == df_b.id) 
df_a_new = df_a.join(df_b, cond, how ='full').withColumn('val_new', F.when(cond, df_b.val_1))
df_a_new = df_a_new.drop(*['id', 'val_1', 'val_2'])
df_a_new = df_a_new.filter(df_a_new.idx. isNotNull())
df_a_new.show()
```

How can I get the proper output as expected result with correct index order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign an increasing index to `df_a` and sort by that index after joining. Also I'd suggest doing a left join rather than a full join.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_a_new = df_a.withColumn('index', F.monotonically_increasing_id()) \
               .join(df_b, df_a.col_p == df_b.id, 'left') \
               .orderBy('index') \
               .select('idx', 'col_n', 'col_p', 'val_1')

df_a_new.show()
+----+-----+-----+-----+
| idx|col_n|col_p|val_1|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
|1412|   31|    1|    1|
|2422|   21|    1|    1|
|4223|   22|    2|    1|
|2244|   43|    1|    1|
|1235|   54|    1|    1|
|4126|   12|    5|    2|
|2342|   44|    1|    1|
+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to choose columns if I have many?

Comment: use `select` to choose columns @xcen

Comment: ex: if ```df_a``` has 50 columns, do I have to add all columns?

Comment: then use `drop` to remove columns from `df_b` instead @xcen

Answer (score 1):

you need to create your own indexes (monotomically_increasing_ids) and sort again after joining on those indexes.
But there is no way you can join while preserving order in spark as the rows are partitioned before joining and they lose order before combining
refer: [Can Dataframe joins in Spark preserve order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085801/can-dataframe-joins-in-spark-preserve-order)

Comment: It is possible to preserve order. See the answer to your referenced question, which uses `monotonically_increasing_id`, as I did in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I meant there is no direct way in which you can avoid shuffling, you need to sort it after joining