# Would zipWithIndex after sc.textFile give the correct line numbers?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say If I do, something as shown below.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("someFile.txt")
val rddWithLines = rdd.zipWithIndex
```

Would the indices added by zipWithIndex correspond to the line numbers (first line being 0 of course) in the input file? Or is it that the order gets broken in this case?

Comment: That should work: "For example, if you read a file (sc.textFile) the lines of the RDD will be in the order that they were in the file." from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29301258/2661491)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zipWithIndex` is a map-only transformation (it doesn't shuffle) so order will be correct. You can safely use it here.

Answer (score -2):

SparkContext.textFile can create multiple partitions for each file. If these partitions are in the correct order you should get the correct result. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012187/2829135) for more information.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  zipWithIndex does exactly what the OP wants, regardless of partitioning.

Comment: I agree as long as the partitions are in the correct order.

Comment: How would they be out of order?  Ordered partitions is a guarantee of the HadoopRDD class which `sc.textFile` uses.

Comment: @TimP Would the ordering be preserved even in case of reading multiple files through sc.textFile?

Comment: Loading multiple text files with `sc.textFile` is just like loading each one separately with `sc.textFile` and unioning the result. The partitions from each file will be ordered.