# How to use groupby and nth_value at the same time in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

So, I have a dataset with some repeated data, which I need to remove. For some reason, the data I need is always in the middle:

```
--> df_apps
DATE       |  APP       |  DOWNLOADS  |  ACTIVE_USERS
______________________________________________________
2021-01-10 |  FACEBOOK  |  1000       |  5000
2021-01-10 |  FACEBOOK  |  20000      |  900000
2021-02-10 |  FACEBOOK  |  9000       |  72000
2021-01-11 |  FACEBOOK  |  4000       |  2000
2021-01-11 |  FACEBOOK  |  40000      |  85000
2021-02-11 |  FACEBOOK  |  1000       |  2000
```

In pandas, it'd be as simple as `df_apps_grouped = df_apps.groupby('DATE').nth_value(1)` and I'd get the result bellow:

```
--> df_apps_grouped
DATE       |  APP       |  DOWNLOADS  |  ACTIVE_USERS
______________________________________________________
2021-01-10 |  FACEBOOK  |  20000      |  900000
2021-01-11 |  FACEBOOK  |  40000      |  85000
```

But for one specific project, I must use pyspark and I can't get this result on it.
Could you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('date').orderBy('date')
df = df.withColumn('row_n', F.row_number().over(w)).filter('row_n ==1')
```

Because of its distributed nature the rows are in random order and row 1 might be different the second time you query it. This is why you need an order by, this will make sure you get the same result every time

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`row_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html) applied over the a window partitioned by `DATE` and ordered by `DATE`, however due to the distributed nature of spark, we can't guarantee that during ordering

```
2021-01-10 |  FACEBOOK  |  1000       |  5000
```

will always come before

```
2021-01-10 |  FACEBOOK  |  20000      |  900000
```

I would suggest, including a line number if you are reading from a file, and ordering based on the file number. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898344/would-zipwithindex-after-sc-textfile-give-the-correct-line-numbers) for achieving this in Spark.