# Queueing Spark applications using spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have many spark 1.6 applications which I want to run one after another (as they read/write from the same hive tables) using YARN

I tried specifying a common queue using `spark-submit --queue QUENAME ...` but the applications still run in parallel.

is there another way to ensure only 1 application runs at the same time (other than using a loop e.g. a bash-script?)

Comment: wanting to run **cluster computing** jobs sequentially pretty much defeats the purpose of the framework ... you dont need apache spark for sequential execution, that doesnt make any sense. Write a bash script and be happy - thats what bash scripts are made for.

Comment: @specializt Thanks for the comment. I agree in general, but I have reasons to do it sequentially (of course all my individual spark-applications run distributed), I just don't want them to run all at the same time (for which I have good reasons)

Comment: then collect all the jobs onto one single machine and run it, [RDDs preserve order](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29301258/351861)

Comment: why can't you run as oozie workflow job where each spark action can run sequentially

Comment: This might help you https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/25580/scheduling-a-spark-submit-job-using-oozie.html