# RDD: Preserve total order when repartitioning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

It seems one of my assumptions were incorrect regarding order in RDDs ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284095/which-operations-preserve-rdd-order)).

Suppose I wish to repartition a RDD after having sorted it.

```
import random

l = list(range(20))
random.shuffle(l)

spark.sparkContext\
.parallelize(l)\
.sortBy(lambda x:x)\
.repartition(3)\
.collect()
```

Which yields:

```
[16, 17, 18, 19, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

As we can see, the order is preserved ***within*** a partition but the total order is not preserved over all partitions.

I would like to preserve total order of the RDD, like so:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

I am having difficulty finding anything online which could be of assistance. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: make it single partition using coalesce(1)

Comment: @Kishore, I work with billions of rows, so unfortunately this won't work.

Comment: Would sorting after repartitioning not be an option?

Comment: @shaido, it certainly will be. Does it preserve the partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that we can provide the argument `numPartitions=partitions` to the `sortBy` function to partition the RDD and preserve total order:

```
import random

l = list(range(20))
random.shuffle(l)

partitions = 3

spark.sparkContext\
.parallelize(l)\
.sortBy(lambda x:x ,numPartitions=partitions)\
.collect()
```