# Does Dataframe coalesce in Spark preserve order?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, rdd, shuffle

I use coalesce(1) to write a Dataframe to single file, like this.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv")
  .option("header", true).mode("overwrite").save(output_path)
```

A quick glance at the file shows that the order was preserved, but is it always the case? If the order is not preserved, how can I enforce it? The coalesce function of RDD has an extra parameter to disallow shuffling, but the coalesce method of Dataframe only takes 1 parameter.

Comment: Specify the `orderBy` after coalesce to enforce ordering

Comment: May be time for the high priest to indicate an answer.

Comment: I think this will need some effort to figure out, although it has been discussed again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284095/which-operations-preserve-rdd-order. Take a look at Avseiytsev Dmitriy answer. It seems that currently there is no guarantee for order retention of the final RDD. This is the class responsible for the coalesce algorithm https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/89c98a4c7068734e322d335cb7c9f22379ff00e8/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/CoalescedRDD.scala#L156

Answer (score 2):

If you read a file (`sc.read.text`) the lines of the `DataFrame/Dataset/RDD` will be in the order that they were in the file.

`list, map, filter,coalesce and flatMap` do preserve the order. 
  `sortBy, partitionBy and join` do not preserve the order.

The reason is that most `DataFrame/Dataset/RDD` operations work on Iterators inside the partitions. So map or filter just has no way to mess up the order.

In case of if you choose to use `HashPartitioner` and invoking invoke `map` on `DataFrame/Dataset/RDD` will change the key. In this case you can use `partitionBy` to restore the partitioning with a shuffle.