# How to zip two RDDs (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, zip, rdd, databricks

I have two RDDs which have this form:

**RDD A:** (Columns: icchID, X_Coord)

```
[ICCH 1,10.0]
[ICCH 2,10.0]
[ICCH 4,100.0]
[ICCH 4,100.0]
[ICCH 2,13.0]
```

**RDD B:** (Columns: Y_Coord, Class)

```
[10.0,A]
[64.0,B]
[39.0,A]
[9.0,C]
[80.0,D]
```

I would like to combine those two RDDs so that I have an RDD which has this form:

```
[ICCH 1,10.0,10.0,A]
[ICCH 2,10.0,64.0,B]
[ICCH 4,100.0,39.0,A]
[ICCH 4,100.0,9.0,C]
[ICCH 2,13.0,80.0,D]
```

Note that both RDDs have the same Rows and Columns. Is it possible to do this using Scala?

P.S. I am a noob at Scala. I am using Databricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using the RDD `zip` method along with a transformation via `map`:

```
val rddA = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("ICCH 1", 10.0), ("ICCH 2", 10.0), ("ICCH 4", 100.0), ("ICCH 5", 100.0), ("ICCH 2", 13.0)
))

val rddB = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (10.0, "A"), (64.0, "B"), (39.0, "A"), (9.0, "C"), (80.0, "D")
))

val zippedRDD = (rddA zip rddB).map{ case ((id, x), (y, c)) => (id, x, y, c) }
// zippedRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Double, Double, String)] = ...

zippedRDD.collect
// Array[(String, Double, Double, String)] = Array(
//   (ICCH 1,10.0,10.0,A), (ICCH 2,10.0,64.0,B), (ICCH 4,100.0,39.0,A), (ICCH 5,100.0,9.0,C), (ICCH 2,13.0,80.0,D)
// )
```

Be cautioned though maintaining the ordering between two RDDs is a tricky matter.  Here's a relevant [`SO link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268210/mind-blown-rdd-zip-method) about the ordering issue.

And below is what the Spark API doc re: RDD [`zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@zip[U](other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U])(implicitevidence$10:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(T,U)]) method says :

```
def zip[U](other: RDD[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[(T, U)]
```

> Zips this RDD with another one, returning key-value pairs with the
>   first element in each RDD, second element in each RDD, etc. Assumes
>   that the two RDDs have the *same number of partitions* and the *same
>   number of elements in each partition* (e.g. one was made through a map
>   on the other).

Comment: Hello and sorry for the late answer. I tested your recomendation and I get this error: `error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type/found   : (T1, T2)/
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Row`. Do you know what could cause it?

Comment: @Aris Kantas, maybe your rddA and rddB are `RDD[Row]` (which is essentially a DataFrame) rather than the general `RDD[T]`.  If so, the `zip/map` code line can be changed to `(rddA zip rddB).map{ case (Row(id: String, x: Double), Row(y: Double, c: String)) => (id, x, y, c) }`.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much for your help! Hope you have a nice day!