# Compare rows in RDD and filter out

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filter, rdd

I have a sorted RDD, I have already applied some filters to it before. It’s not a key value pair.

I want to remove rows of the RDD. Given two consecutive rows, I would like to remove the second if some elements are the same in both.

I tried zip the RDD with itself, but what I get is pairs of the exact same row.

Could this be done with some group/reduce… ?

Comment: it's be good to share a tiny reproducible data example to play with. see [mcve]

Comment: The answers to this question is what you need to know about the `rdd1.zip(rdd2)` method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268210/mind-blown-rdd-zip-method